# How to configure/save layout of SQL Server's Log File Viewer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I'm viewing the job history of a particular SQL Agent Job, I typically want to see whether it succeeded, its duration and maybe the duration of the individual steps of the job.

When I open the history in the Log File Viewer, I always need to scroll over and shrink the 'Message' column and drag the 'Duration' column over next to the 'Step Name' column.

Is there a way to configure the layout of the Log File Viewer (e.g. reposition columns, resize columns) and save it for future sessions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no.  The log and activity viewers have no persistable configuration options in SQL Server Management Studio.  You'd need to find a 3rd party viewer or build a custom one.